# Remapping SysRq in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, sysrq

The designers of my new keyboard decided that for some f:in reason the PrintScreen key must sit between <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>.

So now I have this problem: I like having the magic SysRq key available because it has been useful every now and then. But now I have, for example, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> mapped to <kbd>downarrow</kbd> and a moment ago when I wanted to use this <kbd>downarrow</kbd> combination, I accidentally pressed <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd><kbd>+k</kbd> and all programs were killed. This is extremely annoying.

Is there any way to remap sysrq somewhere else? Like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> or something.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem on my new laptop. My solution was to patch `drivers/tty/sysrq.c` in the kernel to add

```c
#undef KEY_SYSRQ
#define KEY_SYSRQ KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
```

right after all the `#include`s. If volume-down is not an appropriate key for you, you can find other keycodes in `include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h`.

I don't see any way to do this remapping without modifying the kernel. If that's not an option, one can at least use `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` as described in [the kernel's sysrq documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) to disable the more dangerous requests:

```bash
echo 0x1A >/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

This only enables control of logging levels, process dumps and sync. Most of the other categories will probably interrupt your work after an accidential trigger.

Comment: I have seen that in `include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h` there is `#define KEY_SYSRQ  99`, and in `usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h` there is `#define KEY_SYSRQ  99`. Maybe that's a cleaner way to redifine it by redifining it there?

Comment: @GolarRamblar I don't think that's a good idea. To the kernel, `SYSRQ` is the name of that key, much like `F12` or `A`. That header is also used in user space, you can find it in `/usr/include/linux` as well. I just want to change which key triggers the sysrq action and not mess up the input system. The proper solution would of course be to make the sysrq trigger configurable via boot parameter and/or some `/proc` file. For a hack like this. you usually want to make the smallest possible change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @wrtlprnft. -- What are the problems with remapping it by [modifying the scancodes-keycodes-mapping after bootup within the kernel](/a/1749986/437492)? For me, this at least makes a new key behaving as SysRq. I cannot test if that makes the old one not behaving anymore as SysRq, because I don't have that key physically.

Comment: @GolarRamblar Woudn't that completely remap the target key? i. e. if I remapped the volume-down key of my keyboard to `SYSRQ` and mapped the printscreen key to something useless like `F13`, wouldn't both keys stop working for their normal purpose? Of course, I could then tell KDE to reduce the volume on `SYSRQ`, but if I then plug in an external keyboard, that would also have the same strange mapping. Also note that patching and compiling Linux seems to be far easier (to me) than messing with udev.

Comment: Yes, @wrtlprnft, that completely remaps the key. But you can also swap key assignments this way (given you do it one-shot, not sequentially, at least with `setkeycodes` you have to do all remappings where you have a chain of moving keys arounf within one command). The udev method works per device: You can specify which device(s) to apply the rules to, so you can limit it to the internal keyboard. And the `setkeycodes` method somehow does _not_ work for USB keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

## Remapping via scancode-keycode-remapping (kernel side)

### Via udev:

Another way could be remapping scancodes to keycodes. `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` gives on my system a good introduction about what to do (it is verbosely documented), alternatively: You can read for example [here](https://yulistic.gitlab.io/2017/12/linux-keymapping-with-udev-hwdb/), and so I created a [file `94-gpd-micropc-keyboard.hwdb`](http://ix.io/4ejy) for my computer which contains

```
[...]
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:br*:efr*:svnGPD:pnMicroPC:*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_36=sysrq  # Right Shift -> SysRq
[...]
```

*(see [full file](http://ix.io/4eKf) for more more general documentation in the comments)*

and afterwards I run `udevadm --debug hwdb --update` and then `udevadm trigger /dev/input/<my-input-device>` to load it without reboot.

Now the right shift is the SysRq key and it works as SysRq, without doing anything to the kernel's code.

Note:

- With the `evdev:*`-line it can be fine-tuned to which keyboards the settings should be applied.

### Directly without udev, via `setkeycodes`:

There is also an option without involving udev, via `setkeycodes`, and what you need you can infer from `showkey -s`. (Only on the Linux text console, not in X Server and probably not in wayland.)

Note:

- this applies to all AT/ PS/2-connected keyboards,
- this seems to ignore USB-connected keyboards.

---

To un-map your original SysRq key, the same should work to map the SysRq key to something else. Since I don't have a physical SysRq key I cannot test and query it's scancode via `showkey` (`setkeycodes`-method) or `evtest` (udev-method).

---

I actually would like to have SysRq only be registered when a modifier key is pressed, e.g. `<Ctrl>`+`<Right Shift>`, so that "normal" right shift still stays as such. Any idea if that can be achieved without changing the keyboard controller's firmware?

Answer (score -2):

The answer depends on whether you are running X (a current generation gui desktop) or not. You didn't specify.

Running X:

There are several ways to handle this.

The most precise/limited way is to use `xmodmap`. I haven't used it, so I'm not familiar with the details. It will remap keys with specific key codes to specific key symbols.

If you have trouble sorting things out, run `xev`. When you press any key combination (or do other X things), `xev` will tell you what the system saw which will give you the values you need for `xmodmap`.

Once you get the command to work, you can run it from your `~/.login` script so it's there when you start an interactive shell. Or, you can add it as a bash script into your desktop environment's autostart system.

If you want to do more, you may want to check out `AutoKey` which is a desktop automation tool. Among other things, you can define a macro which will be triggered by a simple or compound keypress which can do anything from just emitting another keypress to running a complex macro coded in Python which can do almost anything you can think of - if you know enough Python.

I use it every day and love it.

For simpler things along the same lines, check out `xdotool`. It can also do a few things which `AutoKey` currently can't do - like emit mouse events.

Not running X (server installation, etc.):

This is a lot harder to find information on because it's a much less common case.

I've never tried it, but I did find some information on it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1021839#p1021839) yesterday answering another question.

Comment: Actually I already remapped the key but it seems the kernel captures the sysrq combinations before X sees them or something.

Comment: Upon rereading your question, I see that I missed that you had already done that.